# How to remove www from url and use subfolder at the same time?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have no or very little knowledge about URL rewriting. I am using a multi-domain host on HostGator and facing a problem. I want to place each website in a folder including primary domain.

So I want to place my website like

```
public_html/site1
public_html/site2
public_html/site3
```

HostGator says that my primary domain must be pointed to `public_html` folder and I cannot point it directly to `site1` folder. I will need to use url rewriting here. I don't want `www` in my primary domain's URL and I want to run the website from subdirectory.

Can anybody please give me full code for this? My main problem is primary domain. Secondary domains I can manage.

Comment: @Mike Anthony  Thank you for correcting the question. It looks much better now. I see that you have asked many questions similar to this. If possible then please tag someone who can answer this question. Thank you for the great help.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for redirecting the primary domain i.e `site1.com` to subdirectory `/site1`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site1.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site1/index.php [L]
```

But i am still unable to remove `www.` from my url for primary domain

Comment: Please rather add this as an edit to your question, and then delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but it doesnt work. Any suggestions. I used it just below my above provided code.

Comment: just use this and try

Comment: if i use just your provided code then it removes www, But it doesnt point to the subdirectory. I guess we need to add code for that. I have no knowledge of .htaccess code

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but it is a combination of your original code, and Swaraj's answer:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove www. from primary domain
# per Swaraj's answer
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,QSA,NC,L]

# Per your code, rewrite to site1 directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1

# Per your code, show primary domain root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site1/index.php [L]
```